# page header logo overlapping page header text

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, logos

I am using the following LaTeX source to place a logo into page header:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{./docs/log4cplus}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-4\baselineskip}
```

Unfortunately, when the text is long, it overlaps the logo:

[image: overlapping text/logo]

Can I fix this by raising the logo a little bit or by inserting some vertical white space on pages where the header text is too long/overlaps?

Comment: Modify the `\includegraphics[]{}` to be  `\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{./docs/log4cplus}}}`, which will move the graphic up one line space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, shift up the graphic with a `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{%
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{./docs/log4cplus}}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-4\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\section{A very long header, very long indeed}
My section text
\end{document}
```

[image]