# Can't put a header logo image and footer text

Tags: header-footer, memoir

Well. I'm writing a manual to my work.
And I have to put a header with the logo image and a footer for the pages.
I'm trying to use \lhead{...} \cfoot{...} just to see if it work. but I just can't make it work.

here is my code style.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\STARTCODE\relax 
\let\STOPCODE\relax 
\STARTCODE
\usepackage{fourier} % or what ever
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}%. Sans serif - Helvetica
\usepackage{color,calc}
\newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
\definecolor{ChapBlue}{rgb}{0.00,0.65,0.65}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\thickhrulefill}{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand*\BuildChpNum[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut}  \\[.5ex]
    \colorbox{ChapBlue}{%
      \rule[-10em]{0pt}{0pt}%
      \rule{1ex}{0pt}\color{black}#2\strut
      \rule{1ex}{0pt}}%
  \end{tabular}}
\makechapterstyle{BlueBox}{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedright\Huge\bfseries}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{20pt}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{26pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
      \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
      {\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
      \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
      {\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}}}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
    \parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
      \vspace{\midchapskip}%
      \thickhrulefill\par
      \chaptitlefont ##1\par}}%
}
\chapterstyle{BlueBox}
\STOPCODE
\setlength\afterchapskip {\onelineskip }
\setlength\beforechapskip {\onelineskip }

%ligando a numeração da subsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}

%alterando nome da tabela e da figura
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura: }
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela: }

%cabeçalho
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{LOGO IMAGE HERE}
\cfoot{TEXT HERE}

%Margem
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3cm}

%tamanho que o texto ocupa
\textwidth=16cm

%fazendo os footers
\pagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%para tabelas grandes
\usepackage{longtable}

%para colocar um width maximo para as figuras do comando
%[max width = ...]
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%packages inseridos que não são do estilo.

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159626/page-header-logo-overlapping-page-header-text

Comment: `memoir` provides it own facilities to place headers and footers. using fancyhdr will only break stuff. Please be aware of that. If you want to use `fancyhdr`, you need to use `\pagestyle{fancy}`, but since this package uses commands, that are obsolete for 20 years now, you need to enable this memoir-feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

`memoir` provides it own facilities to place headers and footers. Using `fancyhdr` will only break stuff. Please be aware of that. If you really want to use `fancyhdr`, you need to use `\pagestyle{fancy}`, but since this package (fancyhdr) uses commands, that are obsolete for 20 years now, you need to enable the memoir option `oldfontcommands`.

Here is the proper way to do the job.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makepagestyle{guilherme}
\makeevenhead{guilherme}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-1x1}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{guilherme}{}{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-1x1}}
\makeevenfoot{guilherme}{}{TEXT}{}
\setlength{\headheight}{35pt}
\pagestyle{guilherme}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Me If You Can}
\blindtext

\blindtext[14]
\end{document}
```